# Maximum and Minimum using loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, max, min

I had to rearrange code so that when I run the program the output is:

My attempt allowed the output to do everything except print the maximum or the minimum. Have tried moving `count = count + 1` outside the loop to no avail. Still a beginner, any help is appreciated. my attempt:

```
value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
number = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter: "))
count = 1
largest = value
smallest = value
while count <= number :
    value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
    count = count + 1
    if value > largest :
        largest = value
        print("The maximum is: ", largest)
    if value < smallest :
        smallest = value
        print("The minimum is: ", smallest)
```

expected output:

```
Enter an input value: 3
How many numbers would you like to enter: 7
Enter an input value: 2
Enter an input value: 9
Enter an input value: 23
Enter an input value: 4
Enter an input value: 1
Enter an input value: 8
Enter an input value: 3
The maximum is:  23
The minimum is:  1
```

Comment: Please post output as text, not an image of text.

Comment: You can't know what the max or min *is* until after the loop has completed, so you can't print either before that.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the `print` at the **end** of your code, only after you have tested **all elements**:

```
value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
number = int(input("How many numbers would you like to enter: "))
count = 1
largest = value
smallest = value
while count <= number :
    value = int(input("Enter an input value: "))
    count = count + 1
    if value > largest :
        largest = value
    if value < smallest :
        smallest = value
print("The maximum is: ", largest)
print("The minimum is: ", smallest)
```

output:

```
Enter an input value: 3
How many numbers would you like to enter: 7
Enter an input value: 2
Enter an input value: 9
Enter an input value: 23
Enter an input value: 4
Enter an input value: 1
Enter an input value: 8
Enter an input value: 3
The maximum is:  23
The minimum is:  1
```